# Is there are working Drag&Drop library for Vue 3 with option to have multidrag?

Tags: vue.js, drag-and-drop

I have two tables and I want to add Drag&Drop function, looking for vue sortablejs and vue draggablen, but these librarys are old and maybe even out of update. Main goal is to add multidrag option, so that I can move more rows at one drag.
Thank you!

I tried use vue draggable, but found a lot of mistakes and don't know how to add multidrag option.